# PHP code for parsing JSON

Tags: php, json

Hi everyone can somebody tell me how we can get this with php

```
  {
    "image": "http:....jpg",
    "caption": "Super Commando Dhruva",
    "username": "bill",
    "comments": [
        "abc",
        "efg",
        "hij",
        "klm"
    ]
},
```

this is giving me 4 objects in the JSON code

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    array_push($result, array('image'=>$row[0],'caption'=>$row[1],'username'=>$row[2],
    'comments'=>array($row[3])));

}
echo json_encode($result);
```

ok guys here is also the select statement:

```
"SELECT Post.image, Post.caption, Post.username, comments.comments FROM Post JOIN comments ON (Post.id=comments.post_id)";
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Use json_decode($json_string, true);

Comment: Is it just me or is everyone else missing the point here? You want to convert your result set *to* json, not from... I assume the crux of your question is: how do I create the nested array of comments? I think you need to update your question to provide an example of your data; the `SELECT` statement might be useful too.

Comment: I agree with @DarraghEnright it seems that you want your data output to be in JSON (which you have already done with json_encoded()) please be a little more descriptive

Comment: Okay, a few interesting implications here - will post some suggestions presently.

Comment: Posted an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a few things here...

### Your result set

You are not performing a `GROUP BY` on your query. Based on your `JOIN`, you will get a row back for each `comments` record with a relationship to a `Post` record

Two points about this:

1. Your query will not return any `Post` record that does not have any comments. If you require this, use `LEFT JOIN`.
2. A row will be returned for every `comments` record with a relationship to a `Post` record. If a `Post` record has three `comments`, you will get three rows, which implies some duplication in your result set.

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e2e9/5) to see what I mean.

In any case, you'll end up with a result set that will look something like this.

[image]

This is fine - probably not optimal - it implies that you would have to do some filtering to your result set on the PHP level.

### Creating an iterable result set

Let's explore how to handle this. If your `Post` table has a primary/unique column, add that to your `SELECT` query. Let's assume `Post` has a primary key column called `id`:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.image, 
       p.caption, 
       p.username, 
       c.comments 
  FROM Post AS p 
  JOIN comments c 
    ON p.id = c.post_id;
```

Your result set now looks like this:

[image]

If you are using PHP >= 5.3, you can save yourself some boilerplate... Forget the `while` loop and use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to return the entire result set in a single call.

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Also note, the flag `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. The variable `$rows` is an array of the result set as associative arrays. For example, if you `print_r($rows)` my example you get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [image] => bob.jpg
            [caption] => I am Bob!
            [username] => Bob
            [comment] => First!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [image] => bob.jpg
            [caption] => I am Bob!
            [username] => Bob
            [comment] => I concur
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [image] => bob.jpg
            [caption] => I am Bob!
            [username] => Bob
            [comment] => I <3 SO
        )

)
```

### Iterating over and modifying the result set

We would now need to iterate over this result set, grouping it and nesting the comments. There are a million ways to do this - one standard, mechanical way would be:

```
<?php

// ...

$results = [];

// iterate over each row
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    // create a key from the unique/primary key
    $key = $row['id'];

    // add to results, initialise nested comments
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $results)) {
        $results[$key] = [
            'image'    => $row['image'],
            'caption'  => $row['caption'],
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'comments' => [],
        ];
    }

    // add the nested comment, if it's not null
    if (null !== $row['comment']) {
        $results[$key]['comments'][] = $row['comment'];
    }
}

// echo... array_values removes the keys from `$results`
// and re-establishes a standard 0-indexed array
echo json_encode(array_values($results), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

For my example, this yields:

```
[
    {
        "image": "bob.jpg",
        "caption": "I am Bob!",
        "username": "Bob",
        "comments": [
            "First!",
            "I concur",
            "I <3 SO"
        ]
    }
]
```

If you perform your query with a `LEFT JOIN` then the json `comments` field will be an empty array for any record that does not have related comments.

### Alternative suggestion

Another approach would be to modify your query, `GROUP BY` the `Post.id` and perform a MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` on the comments field, defining a separator character. Then you could iterate over the result set and `explode()` on that separator character and do the nesting that way. For example:

```
SELECT p.image, 
       p.caption, 
       p.username, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.comments SEPARATOR '%%%') AS comments
  FROM Post AS p 
  JOIN comments c 
    ON p.id = c.post_id
 GROUP BY p.id;
```

Note that you no longer need `p.id`. This would yield one row per `Post` record; e.g:

[image]

As you can see your comments are now concatenated into a single string, with each comment delimited by `%%%`:

> First!%%%I concur%%%I <3 SO

In PHP, iterate over that result set; e.g:

```
// note that we are handling row data by reference
foreach ($rows as &$row) {
    // explode the comments string 
    // on '%%%' and reassign value 
    // to comments field
    $row['comments'] = explode('%%%', $row['comments']);
}

$result = json_encode($rows);
```

This entails less PHP code, and may (or may not) be faster, but it is also potentially brittle; if you defined a separator that appeared in your comments, you would end up exploding your data into unintended chunks... YMMV. But it's always good to know that there's more than one way to skin a cat!

#### Reference

- [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)
- [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
- [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)
- [Passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a = '{
               "image": "http:....jpg",
               "caption": "Super Commando Dhruva",
               "username": "bill",
               "comments": [
                   "abc",
                   "efg",
                   "hij",
                   "klm"
               ]
           }';

           $b = json_decode($a);

           print_r($b);
```

use `json_decode` function for it.

Comment: The OP is asking how they transform their data to json, not from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the structure of what you presented and understand it:

```
Array
(
   key: value,
   key: value,
   key: Array
   (
      Value, Value, Value
   )
)
```

In PHP that would be:

```
$items = array("key" => "value",
               "key" => "value",
               "key" => array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"));

print_r(json_encode($items));
```

Now, if you would like to put that into multiple arrays while looping, you just need to declare the variable before the loop and tell the array it will receive multiple arrays.

```
$items = array();

for(myLoop)
{
   $items[] = array("key" => "value",
                    "key" => "value",
                    "key" => array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"));
}
```